# Easy way to not display id field in SQLFORM.grid?

Tags: web2py

Is there a quick way to get an SQLFORM.grid to not show the id field values of its entries (i.e. something to the effect of SQLFORM()'s 'showid = False')? I know you can do this by explicitly specifying which fields to show, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the "readable" attribute to False:

```
db.mytable.id.readable = False
```

Comment: Ah, that's right - was intent to find some function parameter that takes care of that, and did not even consider that approach. Thanks!